# sort numerically not alphabetically using displaytag

Tags: jsp, displaytag

I am using displaytag,While sorting the data I am getting output like
1
10
100
2
3
instead of numerical sort. I change the datatype to number. so while doing orderby query in
database ,it sorted correctly ,but when I click on row_number column for resort it gives 
aphabetically sort Not numerical . Please help

Comment: my jsp is like <display:column property="row_number" title="ROW" sortable="true" /> and while adding to list I am uisng query like SELECT * FROM BULK_DETAILS where username=? and file_name=? ORDER BY(RowNumber)"; and RowNumber is NUmber datatype in table but while resort using sort="true" I am getting aphabetical order like
1,10,100,2

Comment: or else can anybody tell me how to display number 000000001 as 1 while displaying a page using displaytag . format can use in this case?

Comment: Thanks for reply can please you u give me example .

Comment: Try this..<display:column property="property-name" format="{0,number,0} $" sortable="true"/>

Comment: I tried not working it giving output like 000000001 but I want that only 1 can be display.